# Best way to allocate large memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

In my Visual C++ app, I know the total objects(CMyObject) to be allocated is 16728064 and each object is 64 byte, so the total memory to be allocated is 1GB. The memory will be allocated in the beginning, used in the whole lifetime of the app, and release in the end.

In such a case, what is the best way to allocate the memory?

Current I try to allocate the memory at the beginning, as follows:

```
    CMyObject *p = new CMyObject[16728064];

    // Perform tasks.

    delete [] p;
```

But the allocation will fail for most of the time. Now I want to do as follows:

```
    CMyObject *p[10];

    p[0] = new CMyObject[1672806];

    p[1] = new CMyObject[1672806];

    …

    // Perform tasks

    Delete [] p[0];

    ….
```

This seems to work for some time.

Therefore, should I split the allocation into pieces as small as possible? Or are there any good solutions for such a situation?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running on a 32-bit or 64-bit platform?

Comment: Do you need all that memory as a part of the working set, or can you store some of it to disk?

Comment: When you allocate one big array, your allocator needs to find one big contiguous region of memory that size.  On 32-bit windows, you are allocating half of the total address space, so finding the contiguous region is not guaranteed.  The amount of memory a process can allocate on Windows can be 2 GB, 3 GB, 4 GB, or 16 TB depending on different factors.

Comment: COMPLETELY UNTESTED CODE: http://ideone.com/ap68Lb

Comment: If that space shall really be used for the duration of the program and there are no dtors which you have to invoke, leave out the delete. Next, you can move to allocating raw pages directly from the OS to remove the overhead of using `new`.

Comment: With some compilers, you can tell the linker to reserve a block of memory and assign variables to that block.  Very popular with embedded systems.  I remember, long ago, that the EXE format could reserve large chunks of memory.  The problem is communicating that to the source code.

Comment: I am using 32bit systems

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes you should split larger allocations into smaller fragments. Depending on your system, it may not have 1GB of contiguous memory.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is X86 processor or something similar, only the virtual address space is contiguous. For X86, physical memory is composed of 4096 byte pages, and the physical pages do  not have to be contiguous, only the mapped virtual address space.

When I run Windows XP 32 bit, on a system with 4GB, it shows 3.6 GB of physical memory available, and usually my test programs don't have a problem with allocating 1 GB, with failures to allocate memory occurring somewhere between 1.5GB and 2GB.

My guess is the reason for failure with large allocations of available physical memory has to do with the operating system as opposed to a processor virtual to physical mapping limitation.

What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows XP(32bit) and there are 2GB physical memory and 32GB disk space for C: drive, the virtual memory seems allocated on C: drive since pagefile.sys is stored on C: